# PHP - prevent html5 input type file attribute multiple hack?

Tags: php, html

Hello I'm doing form upload 4 files field.  Each field can upload 1 file.

but I just know that hacker can hack with firebug to add html5 "multiple" attribute.(see the screenshot)
[image]

and then hacker can upload exceed 4 files now that I don't want to happen.

**Question : How can I do to limit the upload file to 4 files?**

here is my current code

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["file"]["name"]);$i++) {
    if($_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] != "") {
        $split = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);
        $ext = end($split);
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];          //3             


        $targetFile =  "upload/". date('Y-m-d')."_".($i+1).".".$ext;  //5

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
    }
}
```

..

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]"/><br>
    <input type="file" name="file[]"/><br>
    <input type="file" name="file[]"/><br>
    <input type="file" name="file[]"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You could use server side validation if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like this **must** be validated server-side.

```
if(count($_FILES["file"]["name"]) > 4) {
    // show the user an error and refuse to continue
}
```